# What are the names of men's haircuts popular among young Chinese idols?

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, terminology

What are some *popular haircuts among young Chinese idols (preferably men) called in Chinese*? Preferable a list in Chinese, if possible.

For example, take the TFBoy members have haircuts that kind of resemble the Two-block haircut at some point, but I am not sure if in Chinese there are different names for them.

Like, a lot of the haircut/hairstyles I see seem to resemble each other but vary in curves, lengths, etc...

I am trying to discover names of mens' haircut in Chinese so I can search up tutorials on them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, most names of haircuts in China are broad. In our daily life, we are more used to describe the haircut that we want clearly and might make further requests during the haircut.

About the haircuts of TFBoys in your statement, I think it might be called 中分. You can try it. But I am not sure that to what extent your barber can understand you. I'm a little worried that you can only get a similar instead of same hairstyle.

In my opinion, you can just simply try to tell your barber,"我想要理一个王俊凯(the captain of TFBoys)那样的发型".

Comment: 原来如此. I guess I will try as you suggested and describe it during a haircut! Thank you much, though!!